# How to match atom parameter to cond statement clause

Tags: elixir, conditional-statements

I want to place the following functions into one function:

```
def discount(:standard), do: &standard/1
def discount(:bronze), do: &bronze/1
def discount(:silver), do: &silver/1
def discount(:gold), do: &gold/1
```

Something like this:

```
def discount(:rank) do
    cond do
        :standard -> &Shop.standard/1
        :bronze -> &Shop.bronze/1
        :silver -> &Shop.silver/1
        :gold -> &Shop.gold/1
    end
end
```

But how do I match/compare the function parameter *`:rank`* to the atoms in my cond statement? Comparing with `==` doesn't work for me either.

Comment: `:rank` is a constant so it cannot be a parameter variable- name. Use just `rank`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cond`evaluates boolean conditions. If you want to match like that, use `case`:

```rb
def discount(rank) do
  case rank do
    :standard -> &Shop.standard/1
    :bronze -> &Shop.bronze/1
    :silver -> &Shop.silver/1
    :gold -> &Shop.gold/1
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not need the `discount/1` function at all if you use [`apply/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#apply/3):

```elixir
apply(Shop, rank, [arg])
```

In my opinion if choosing between a multiple-clause function and a single function that contains a `case`, the multiple-clause version is better code.

I also wonder why you need to return a function capture, instead of doing something like returning the discount amount, or calculating the discounted value.

Comment: The function should return a function, not apply it.

Comment: The `discount` function just returns a capture of a function in the `Shop` module with the same name as the atom argument. I'm saying that instead of calling the `discount` function, and then calling the returned function, the poster can just use `apply/3` directly.

Comment: That’s right, but that `discout/1` function might be used in the construct like `Enum.each(type, discount(type))`, or its result might be passed further, or whatever. I am saying the code is not exactly equivalent.

Comment: Well that was only half of my answer, the 2nd half was suggesting maybe the code could be simpler ;-)

Comment: Right, right :) I was looking for kinda note that the code is not an exact equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to use a bit of metaprogramming.

```rb
defmodule Shop do
  @types ~w|standard bronze silver gold|a

  Enum.each(@types, fn type ->
    def discount(unquote(type)),
      do: &(__MODULE__.unquote type)/1
  end)

  def gold(_), do: 42
  # ...
end

Shop.discount :gold                                 
#⇒ &Shop.gold/1
```

Comment: Perhaps if I ever pursue or make use of elixir more intensely, I will come back and have a look at this answer :P

Comment: Here it is an obvious overkill, but for 100 different types it would make a perfect sense since adding a new type requires an update of `@types` _only_.